# Fail to connect from MySQL Workbench to remote server

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

After trying many different suggestions as found on the net, I'm still unable to establish a connection from the Workbench application to the server. Here is a brief list of things I tried:

1) Granting all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'%' ; (+flush privileges),

2) Creating a new user 'test'@'%' and granting all privileges (yes, it is the same as above, but had to try with someone different from root),

3) Create a user as 'test2'@'' with all privileges,

4) Turning off firewall in both server and my computer,

5) Updated the file **/etc/my.cfg** my adding a `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` line (there wasn't any such line, to begin with; note the location of this file which differs from what is presented in many posts; in my installation, there is no such a folder /etc/my.cfg/...),

...

The error I get is always that cannot establish a connection (with the 4 steps to check; obviously, I checked them all and it should work).

I have Workbench installed on Windows 10 and I'm using the standard MySQL included in the Oracle Linux 7 installation ISO.

Could anyone suggest additional checks to be made and to find what the issue is?

Comment: Were you able to connect from other client? (Other than workbench). Also, have a look at `skip-networking` value: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-networking

Comment: Thank you @JehadKeriaki for your reply. It turned out that there was nothing wrong with the MySQL parts, but rather with Linux: Firewall and Selinux were up and blocking all accesses from outside. Yes, I know, I should had checked that before posting my question, but you know how it goes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue had nothing to do with MySQL parts. It turned out that Linux's firewall and Selinux were blocking access from outside the server. Once turned off, the connection worked perfectly.

Two things I learned from this:

1) Check better the ENVIRONMENT before blaming the product,

2) MySQL could improve the clarity of the messages and include environment elements that could be the source of the issue (I wasted 1/2 day chasing this stupid issue).

Comment: Please mark your own answer as correct as soon as you can - it might help others. Also, if you'd care to file a bug report/feature request, then post the URL and I'll post a "me-too".

Comment: Of course!! It is just that this forum requires you to wait 1 day to accept your own answer (though I don't understand the motivation for such delay).

Comment: Probably because it's very easy to convince oneself that one is correct - I mean we can always spot the flaw in others, but never in ourselves - O wad some Power the giftie gie us, To see oursels as ithers see us! Burns. This 24 hours gives some time for reflection IMHO.

Comment: Well... yes, but then, if I happen to solve my problem (say) 10 minutes after I posted it, I can write an answer BUT, since I cannot vote for it, other readers would need to go through the whole answer to understand that this is the actual solution. Anyway, that's the way the designers thought and, altogether, they made a terrific job so far!!!

Comment: @FDavidov well i guess several days have passed now, but before your mark your own answer as accepted you should explain how you solved the issue to help others....

Comment: @Xsmael, the explanation is in the body of the post (firewall and Selinux).

Comment: yeah, I meant to include the commands you used

Comment: @Xsmael hummmm.... This is almost 3 years old. I honestly don't remember nor I have the environment at hand to attempt any reverse-engineering (check at config. files). Sorry.

Comment: alright, that's okay :)